# Display GeoTIFF single band image in Python

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, rasterio, matplotlib-basemap

I have a single band GeoTIFF image which displays correctly in QGIS. However I tried viewing the same file using matplotlib and rasterio but I get a different output.
Is there something that I am doing incorrectly?
How do I display it like it is in QGIS?
I would also like to use a colour map for representing the different values of the single band with a color.
The EPSG of the GeoTIFF is 4326.

Here's my code:

```
import os
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from osgeo import gdal


if __name__ == "__main__":
    

    input_Dir = 'generated_46.tif'

  
    tiff_file = input_Dir
    raster = rasterio.open(tiff_file)
    print(raster.crs)

    bbox = raster.bounds

    show(raster.read(),cmap="gray")
```

Here's how it appears in qgis:

[image]

And this is my python output:
[image]

Here is the GeoTIFF description:
[image]
[image]

Comment: @user2856 added

Comment: Check you min and max values! You should outspread them to 0-255 integer range. It is done by QGIS automatic.

Comment: @Zoltan not sure how its done in Python. New to this. Could you help?

Comment: raster = raster / (max(raster) - min(raster)) * 256

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did it

```
raster = rasterio.open(tiff_file)
show(raster)
```

instead of this:

```
show(raster.read(1))
```

[image]